# I am not getting the value in $quote in mulitple currency

Tags: magento-1.7, cart, quote, currency

I am facing the strange issue. I have enabled multi currence on the store but when I change the currency from cart page I seeing entire blank page and getting error'Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted '.While trying to debugg the issue I found that I am not getting the value in $quote.
I am using following code to get quote `$quote= Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();` please help me in this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use following code for quote in your code

```
$quoteId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuoteId(); 
            $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quoteId);
```

Hope this helps. Mine worked with this too...